# How to check if element is not in a list, if it isn't, insert it

Tags: prolog

I want, given a list formed by A-B elements ([a-b,b-c,c-d]), check if some given element it's already in a list (which I will return), and if it's not, add any "A" or "B" element that is not in the output list yet.

I haven't really found any "easy" enough answer for me to understand yet (like, I found one with mappings and stuff I've never used nor seen).

So the output list would need to only have [a,b,c,d]

edit: what I'm trying to do is, I get called like this:

```
enumerate([a-b,b-c,c-d], EnumNodes, EnumArcs)
```

And I have to return two lists. First one gives the nodes (with this specific form:

`[enum(1,a),enum(2,b),enum(3,c),enum(4,d)]`,

and second one gives the arcs (the conections) between said nodes.

So I am at the part where I "know" how to count and return items in a list, but I do not know the following:

-How to insert ONLY unique elements in a list

-How to first check if "A" is in the list, if not insert it, and then check if "B" is in the list, if not, insert it (reason for me not knowing this, I can't come with a way of invoking the rule, once it's done, twice, once for each element, each step of recursion, without making a mistake

Comment: You need to show an example query of what you're trying to achieve. The description on its own is unclear. You might also show a link to the closest answer you could find and perhaps pose a specific question about. "Mappings and stuff" doesn't really cover it.

Comment: allright will do, sorry doing it poorly (it was my 3rd edit, I always try to not be too brief or too long/specific).

Comment: You can use `memberchk/2` to determine if an element is in a list.

Comment: That seems like what I was looking for... could you give me an example using memberchk? What I mean is, how would I go to always pass it the full list, since it's going to be called inside another rule, that travels the original input list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a clause like this?

```
% ensure(ELEMENT, LIST_IN, LIST_OUT)

% If X is already a member of L, then the result is L
ensure(X, L, L) :-
    member(X, L), !.

% If not, the result is X appended to L
ensure(X, L, [X | L]).
```

Use:

```
1 ?- ensure(1, [1,2,3], O).
O = [1, 2, 3].

2 ?- ensure(2, [1,3], O).
O = [2, 1, 3].
```

---

I *think* this is the sort of thing you are looking for...

```
% enumerate(CONNECTIONS_IN, NODES_OUT, ARCS_OUT)

enumerate(C, N, A) :-
    enum_nodes(C, [], N, 1),
    create_arcs(C, N, A).

% enum_nodes(CONNECTIONS_IN, NODES_IN, NODES_OUT, START_ID) 
% Fills up NODES_OUT with enums. New IDs start at START_ID...

enum_nodes([], N, N, _).
enum_nodes([A-B | T], N, NOUT, ID) :-
    ensure_node(A, N, NTMP1, ID, ID1),
    ensure_node(B, NTMP1, NTMP2, ID1, ID2),
    enum_nodes(T, NTMP2, NOUT, ID2).

% ensure_node(NODE, NODES_IN, NODES_OUT, ID_IN, ID_OUT)
% Adds enum(ID_IN, NODE) to NODES_IN to produce NODES_OUT if NODE does not already exist in NODES_IN

ensure_node(NODE, NODES_IN, NODES_IN, ID, ID) :-
    member(enum(_, NODE), NODES_IN), !.

ensure_node(NODE, NODES_IN, [enum(ID_IN, NODE) | NODES_IN], ID_IN, ID_OUT) :-
    ID_OUT is ID_IN + 1.

% create_arcs(CONNECTIONS_IN, NODES_IN, ARCS_OUT).  
% Create arcs - makes a list of arc(NODE_ID_1, NODE_ID_2)...

create_arcs([], _, []).
create_arcs([A-B | T], NODES, [arc(NODE_ID_A, NODE_ID_B) | TARCS]) :-
    member(enum(NODE_ID_A, A), NODES),
    member(enum(NODE_ID_B, B), NODES),
    create_arcs(T, NODES, TARCS).
```

Example output:

```
1 ?- enumerate([a-b, c-d, d-a], N, A).
N = [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)],
A = [arc(1, 2), arc(3, 4), arc(4, 1)] .
```

If you do a `trace`, you can see it working...

```
2 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 2 ?- enumerate([a-b, c-d, d-a], N, A).
   Call: (6) enumerate([a-b, c-d, d-a], _G2634, _G2635) ? creep
   Call: (7) enum_nodes([a-b, c-d, d-a], [], _G2634, 1) ? creep
   Call: (8) ensure_node(a, [], _G2740, 1, _G2742) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(enum(_G2731, a), []) ? creep
   Fail: (9) lists:member(enum(_G2731, a), []) ? creep
   Redo: (8) ensure_node(a, [], _G2740, 1, _G2742) ? creep
   Call: (9) _G2747 is 1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 2 is 1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (8) ensure_node(a, [], [enum(1, a)], 1, 2) ? creep
   Call: (8) ensure_node(b, [enum(1, a)], _G2749, 2, _G2751) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(enum(_G2740, b), [enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Fail: (9) lists:member(enum(_G2740, b), [enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Redo: (8) ensure_node(b, [enum(1, a)], _G2749, 2, _G2751) ? creep
   Call: (9) _G2756 is 2+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 3 is 2+1 ? creep
   Exit: (8) ensure_node(b, [enum(1, a)], [enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 2, 3) ? creep
   Call: (8) enum_nodes([c-d, d-a], [enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2634, 3) ? creep
   Call: (9) ensure_node(c, [enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2758, 3, _G2760) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(enum(_G2749, c), [enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Fail: (10) lists:member(enum(_G2749, c), [enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Redo: (9) ensure_node(c, [enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2758, 3, _G2760) ? creep
   Call: (10) _G2765 is 3+1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 4 is 3+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) ensure_node(c, [enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 3, 4) ? creep
   Call: (9) ensure_node(d, [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2767, 4, _G2769) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(enum(_G2758, d), [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Fail: (10) lists:member(enum(_G2758, d), [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Redo: (9) ensure_node(d, [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2767, 4, _G2769) ? creep
   Call: (10) _G2774 is 4+1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 5 is 4+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) ensure_node(d, [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 4, 5) ? creep
   Call: (9) enum_nodes([d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2634, 5) ? creep
   Call: (10) ensure_node(d, [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2776, 5, _G2778) ? creep
   Call: (11) lists:member(enum(_G2767, d), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) lists:member(enum(4, d), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) ensure_node(d, [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 5, 5) ? creep
   Call: (10) ensure_node(a, [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2779, 5, _G2781) ? creep
   Call: (11) lists:member(enum(_G2770, a), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) lists:member(enum(1, a), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) ensure_node(a, [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 5, 5) ? creep
   Call: (10) enum_nodes([], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2634, 5) ? creep
   Exit: (10) enum_nodes([], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 5) ? creep
   Exit: (9) enum_nodes([d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 5) ? creep
   Exit: (8) enum_nodes([c-d, d-a], [enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 3) ? creep
   Exit: (7) enum_nodes([a-b, c-d, d-a], [], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], 1) ? creep
   Call: (7) create_arcs([a-b, c-d, d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2635) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:member(enum(_G2776, a), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:member(enum(1, a), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:member(enum(_G2777, b), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:member(enum(2, b), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Call: (8) create_arcs([c-d, d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2774) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(enum(_G2788, c), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(enum(3, c), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(enum(_G2789, d), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(enum(4, d), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Call: (9) create_arcs([d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2786) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(enum(_G2800, d), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(enum(4, d), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(enum(_G2801, a), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(enum(1, a), [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]) ? creep
   Call: (10) create_arcs([], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], _G2798) ? creep
   Exit: (10) create_arcs([], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], []) ? creep
   Exit: (9) create_arcs([d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [arc(4, 1)]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) create_arcs([c-d, d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [arc(3, 4), arc(4, 1)]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) create_arcs([a-b, c-d, d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [arc(1, 2), arc(3, 4), arc(4, 1)]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) enumerate([a-b, c-d, d-a], [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)], [arc(1, 2), arc(3, 4), arc(4, 1)]) ? creep
N = [enum(4, d), enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)],
A = [arc(1, 2), arc(3, 4), arc(4, 1)] .
```

Comment: exactly!! How come you guys do it so effortlessly!?

Comment: How could I go for calling it inside another rule @BretC ? as in, I have to travel a list, do several operations. Does that have a name in prolog? Calling rules one inside another?

Comment: I think I did the wrong question. Since I am going to construct my own output list, I could check that list each iteration to see if there is said element in my output list, isn't it?

Comment: Allright I will try for this to be the last question. If each iteration I have 0, 1 OR 2 elements to be added to the list (because of the A-B pattern the list has, in which I have to either add A, A and B, B, or nothing at all), how would I do that, before recursively calling my main rule? If then else aren't all that pretty in prolog

Comment: Holy. G. D. I am going to check your edit thoroughly, may take me... a while to fully get it. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!