# How to assign a different value to each node and each arc of a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, prolog

I wanted to ask a somewhat specific question. I had to solve a problem, which I manage to do with some help. I want to explain what I did and then say what I've been told I'm missing.

What I did: Given a list of nodes (a-b,b-c) I return nodes "ids" from 1 to N (like giving them a name, each an unique number). Then, I see which nodes are connected, and calculate the absolute number that subtracting its names/ids gives me (a-b would be 1-2, abs of that is 1. b-c would have 2-3 as values and would get another 1 for their arc. If I had an a-d node, I would return 1-4, so 3 as their arc value).
Then I return the list of nodes and their IDs/values, and the list of the arcs and its values (1,a-b), (1,a-c).

Graphically:

```
    6a
  5    4
1b      2e
2       3
3c      5f
1
4d




    5a
  4   3
1b      2e
1       2
3c      4f


    5a
  4    3
1b      2e
2
3c      
1
4d




    9a
  8    7    
1b      2e
 6      4
7c      6f
2       2
5d      4g
3       1
8h      3i
```

I've worked this by hand so... still no clear algorythm.

What I've been told I'm missing: Each ARC has to have an unique number, too. So not only nodes, but nodes and arc can only have one number, from 1 to N, being N the number of nodes/arcs.

Problem is, I can't figure this out, at all. Closer I get if I do it on paper, I would calculate doing longer and longer ecuations, but not sure that would actually solve anything, so far I found nothing.

The reason for me not understanding this is that the tree/list a-b,b-c would have as nodes:

```
a-3,b-2,c-1 ; and arcs: 2,a-b|1,b-c
```

And another, very simple list like a-b,a-c would have:

```
a-2,b-1,c-3 ; and arcs: 2,a-b|1,a-c
```

This is one possible solution, but if the trees grow bigger, I fail to see how is it possible for each arc to have one value between 1 and N, non repeating, and same for each node. Is this even possible? How should I approach this task/am I missing some kind of point of view?

Thanks in advance.

edit: since I am not being clear with terminology:

```
enumerate(CONNECTIONS_IN, NODES_OUT, ARCS_OUT)

?- enumerate([a-b,b-c], EnumNodos, EnumArcos) returns, as of right now: 

EnumNodos=[(1,a),(2,b),(3,c)]
EnumArcos=[(1,a-b), (1,a-c)]
```

It should give:

```
 EnumNodos=[(3,a),(1,b),(2,c)]
 EnumArcos=[(1,a-b), (2,a-c)]%because each arc HAS to have an unique number from 1 to N-1 (nodes are from 1 to N)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by the problem description. I'm looking for what's given versus what needs to be determined. The "what's given" you stated is "a list of nodes (a-b, b-c)...". But later on, you're implying that a node would be something like `a-3` which has the node name (`a`) and the node value (3). Secondly, your problem statement isn't clear. Are you really just saying you need to generate all possible paths between two given nodes that have unique value differences along the way? I think that's what you're asking, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326510/how-to-check-if-element-is-not-in-a-list-if-it-isnt-insert-it ?

Comment: not quite @BretC , it is indeed that same problem but with the added restrains that I do not quite get how to implement them, nor in prolog nor in any other language

Comment: @lurker I will try to rephrase it: input list of nodes and connections is [a-b,b-c] I return two lists, one of nodes and one of arcs. I do not need to generate all possible paths between two given nodes, I'm saying that for a given path, I have to: 1) give unique numbers to each node 2) give unique numbers to each arc, being the arc's number equal to sustracting each node it connects.

Comment: @keont I apologize I'm not getting this readily. I think consistent terminology is important here. You refer to *node*, *arc*, *list of nodes*, *connections*, and *path(s)*. You are calling `[a-b,b-c]` a list of *nodes*. Is it really a list of connected *arcs* (thus, a *path*)? Isn't `a-b`, for example, an *arc* not a *node*? Where do the node values come from? Do you have facts such as `node_value(a, 3).` given?

Comment: yeah, I think you are completly right @lurker. Problem is how I try to figure the problem at a given moment, I see it one way or another, but makes me explain myself poorly. I do not have facts, just an input that I call list of nodes, but just because it makes it easier for me, because it reflects both nodes and connections, thus arcs. a-b would be an element of the list, which has the following information: there is an 'a' node, a 'b' node, and both are connected. Again, I'm sorry

Comment: If all you have is the input `[a-b, b-c]`, etc, how do you know what the node values are? Also, `[a-b, b-c]` appears to be a *path* (a list of contiguous node connections) and `a`, `b`, and `c` are *nodes*, is that correct?

Comment: That is totally correct @lurker . For me that path is an arc, connecting two nodes, but same thing, I think it is possible to see it different ways. As for the node values, that IS the task I have. What I put as an example is the only thing I have (see edit, that supposed value is my only example). Up untill now, what I have done is: first node I "see" in the list, I assign it 1, next 2... Then I check it's connection and find out the arcs/paths numbers by substracting. Problem is, that does NOT work if arcs/paths need to be unique. And so far I haven't found a way to unify it for every case.